# Installing and Running Postgres

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation

So, I'm running Windows 11 on a Surface Pro 6. Hopefully that gives some background for the issue for any veterans in the constant battle of installing software on Windows.
The core of the issue is that my computer does not understand that PostgreSQL is installed on my machine, b also does, but also refuses to use it.

If you're interested here is the very long stack trace telling you that it doesn't understand postgres is running. This is, by the way, *after* restarting the server; it does say it is running. I've also ensured that it's an environment variable.

```
root@DESKTOP-5NH2GGL:/mnt/c/Users/jason/COSI 166/brandeis_class_hub# service postgresql status
12/main (port 5432): online
root@DESKTOP-5NH2GGL:/mnt/c/Users/jason/COSI 166/brandeis_class_hub# rails test
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client': FATAL:  role "root" does not exist (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/internal_metadata.rb:17:in `enabled?'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:399:in `schema_up_to_date?'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:635:in `block in load_schema_if_pending!'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `all?'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:655:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:909:in `suppress_messages'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:660:in `method_missing'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:655:in `maintain_test_schema!'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/test_help.rb:17:in `<main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from /mnt/c/Users/jason/COSI 166/brandeis_class_hub/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /mnt/c/Users/jason/COSI 166/brandeis_class_hub/test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `block in load_tests'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `load_tests'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:40:in `run'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:33:in `perform'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have been pitched that maybe I need to make a user profile, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that. If there's something that I'm missing, I'm more than happy to figure it out.

In the code I presented above, I attempted to run `rails test`. Since it doesn't understand Postgres is on my computer and running, it fails.

Comment: That "rails test" thing tries to connect to PostgreSQL with a user called `root`, but there is no user called `root`.

Comment: Alright, then I'm not quite sure where to go from there, I presume that means the person I talked to was correct and I need to fix the user profile.